# Permission denied (publickey) error when using scp

Tags: ssh, scp, amazon-ec2, hadoop, passphrase

I had created 3 linux instances on the Amazon EC2 cloud without a passphrase for the private key. I had stored the private key in a file id_rsa in one of my instances(the master) to allow it to ssh into the slaves. I am in the process of configuring hadoop in my nodes.

However, after configuring hadoop in the master node, when i try to push the configuration into the slave using scp, I am prompted to enter the passphrase for id_rsa file. When I leave it empty and hit Enter I get the Permission denied (publickey) error and then Lost connection.

What passphrase should I enter???

I am totally new to ssh so any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

When you ssh to one of these instances from the master what happens?  scp should behave just like ssh in regards to authentication.  If you can't ssh successfully then debug at the ssh level (ssh -v is your friend).  ssh -v will provide information on the steps it's taking to authenticate.  It may not be using your private key, the debug output should show what key it's trying to use.  Also ensure you have permissions setup correctly for this file.